# What was this movie I saw billed as the "Worst SF movie ever"?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, horror, b-movies, undead

Some years ago I watched very old science fiction movie on French television that was advertised as "The worst SF movie ever made".

It involved aliens who somehow woke up the dead, so the living had to fight wave after wave of animated corpses coming out of their graves.

To elaborate on how bad the movie was, one scene I remember showed the alien spaceship "floating in space" with the strings holding it perfectly visible.

This movie was so bad it was totally hilarious. I really enjoyed watching it! Can anyone identify the movie?

Comment: Starcrash is the worst sci-fi movie ever made, but it doesn't match the description. Clearly the advert was lying.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space?wprov=sfla1

Comment: UFOs hanging from visible strings sounds very [*Plan 9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space) which IIRC involved bringing back Earth's dead.  It is widely considered a terrible movie.

Comment: I just checked Starcrash. Much too recent. That was a very old, BW movie. Not a silent movie, not **that** old.... Not that the living dead spoke much, but the living living did, no cards to read as in the oldest Charlie Chaplin "The Tramp" movies...

Comment: @DavidW Sorry, but Adamant beat you by a few seconds....

Comment: My friends, can your heart stand the shocking facts about...grave robbers from outer space?

Comment: @Alfred Which means, considering how much more I wrote, that I type much faster. :)  That's okay, I didn't bother posting an answer.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind that I edited your title; feel free to roll it back.

Comment: If you've enjoyed a movie from Ed Wood, you might enjoy a movie about [Ed Wood](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ed_wood), from Tim Burton. In the same vein, there's [The Disaster Artist](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_disaster_artist). A movie about [The Room](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_room), the best worst movie ever.

Comment: @EricDuminil As a matter of fact, after I was reminded of the title (and thus author) of *Plan 9..* I remembered that french TV also showed on the same day the film by Tim Burton, with Martin Landau as Bela Lugosi, and I saw both. But that was very long ago, I had forgotten the connection. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When I was at MIT, Plan 9 was included every year in our Science Fiction Marathon.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not surprised. So bad it becomes good, yes indeed !

Comment: Fun fact: the (much better but much less successful) successor to the Unix Operating System, created by some of the original developers of Unix, is called Plan 9 from Bell Labs. Those are also some of the same people who (much) later created the Go Programming Language. Also, the ubiquitous UTF-8 encoding was developed as part of Plan 9.

Comment: Although you got your question answered, rest assured that there *is* no worst movie. Mystery Science Theater 3000, and RiffTrax, have repeatedly demonstrated that to be true. There sure are a lot tied for last place, though...my current pick is [Rollergator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207061/).

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Was Bell Labs Plan 9 called after the movie?

Comment: @valorum Darn autocorrect! Somehow yours put the word "Crash" when you typed "Wars episodes 1-3".

Comment: @EricDuminil: I always assumed so, and [Eric S. Raymond claims it in *The Art of Unix Programming*](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/plan9.html#ftn.id3015199), but I don't have a primary source. I always assumed it was a joking nod to the "Worse Is Better" series of articles about Unix, i.e. if Unix is "worse" than LISP Machine, and "Worse is Better", then a successor to Unix should be "Worse than Worse" in order to be better than Unix. So, Plan 9 from Bell Labs should be worse than worse just like Plan 9 from Outer Space is. But that is purely my interpretation.

Comment: The successor of Plan 9 from Bell Labs is named based on a series of references to hell, the underworld, and specifically Dante Aligheri's *Divine Comedy*, i.e. the OS is called *Inferno*, the programming language is called *Limbo*, the VM is called *Dis*, the protocol is called *Styx*. Note that in the Divine Comedy, there are 9 circles of hell.

Comment: Surely "Flesh Gordon" comes first? (Note it's not Flash but Flesh).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This sounds like the infamous [Plan 9 from Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space?wprov=sfla1).

The titular plan involves using pineal and pituitary stimulation to awaken the dead:

> The Ruler : What Plan will you follow now?
>
> Eros : Plan 9. It's been absolutely impossible to work through these earth creatures. Their soul is too controlled.
>
> The Ruler: Plan 9?
>
> The Ruler : Ah, yes. Plan 9 deals with the resurrection of the dead. Long distance electrodes shot into the pineal and pituitary glands of recent dead.

And the aliens responsible fly around in saucers that are [clearly models:](https://fantastic-plastic.com/plan_9_flying_saucer.html)

> In fact, the creation of the "Plan 9" saucers were even more prosaic than that. Instead of using pie plates, Woods' "special effects" team simply drove to their nearest hobby store (This was the late 1950s, when there used to be hobby stores) and purchased a half dozen "Flying Saucer" models made by Lindberg Line. They removed the rocket engines, spray-painted models -- including the clear plastic domes -- silver and -- voila! -- an alien invasion force!

The film has also frequently been considered the worst of all time, and is featured on Wikipedia's [listing of films considered as such.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_considered_the_worst?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Oh yes ! I started checking Plan 9 as soon as you posted your comment. That was the one, yes.

Comment: My friend, you have seen this incident based on sworn testimony. Can you prove that it didn't happen? Perhaps on your way home, you will pass someone in the dark, and you will never know it, for they will be from outer space. Many scientists believe that another world is watching us this moment. We once laughed at the horseless carriage, the aeroplane, the telephone, the electric light, vitamins, radio, and even television! And now some of us laugh at outer space. God help us... in the future.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's an [Ed Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood) film. Tim Burton made an eponymous [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood_(film)) about him, with Johnny Depp in the lead role.

Comment: @Adamant disappointed you left out my favourite line, "Future events such as these will affect you in the future."

Comment: And Ed Wood the worst director of all time :)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I saw the "Ed Wood" movie too at the time. See my answer to Eric Duminil's comment under my question. I had forgotten the connection, the memory came back with the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: IIRC there was a Seinfeld episode where the plot revolved around this movie and how it was the worst movie, not just the worst sci-fi movie.

Comment: It didn't much help that the film's headline star died before filming got properly under way (after only a few test takes, I think)

Comment: It was so bad, an [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) was named after it...

Answer (score 28):

Sounds like "[Plan 9 From Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space)":

- Made in 1957, shot in black and white
- The titular "Plan 9" refers to "a scheme to resurrect the Earth's dead, referred to as "ghouls""
- Awarded the title of "Worst Film Ever" and described as "the epitome of so-bad-it's-good cinema"

Personally I couldn't spot the wires, but these UFO scenes certainly match the caliber:

Comment: Excellent answer, but Adamant beat you by a very short time ! I totally agree with so-bad-it's-good definition.

Comment: The pilot sounds so bored and disinterested when he says "that's nothing from this world".

Comment: Now I'm disappointed... Where are the strings that everybody is talking about? I demand to see them!

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica Later in the movie, on a darker background IIRC, they are quite visible. Just watch the whole thing, it is hilarious...